# While uploading the files one file should not be replaced by another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing problem during uploading the files. please help me in this.

1. while I am uploading the files one by one it is replacing the first uploaded files.
2. If the user drags a second set of files then the uploaded shall be the union of these files.

I have did the coding like this way,just see that:-
kindly go through this link:-
http://pastebin.com/syyVbw3A

Comment: What have you done till now? Show us some code!

Comment: My car is not starting up. I don't know the manufacturer, model and the fuel it use.

Comment: we won't have any idea on what to answer unless you post some code of what you have done so far. We do not have crystal balls.

Comment: I have updated my question please see that,please go through the given link which i have attached with the question.

Answer (score 0):

this problem has nothing to do with jquery or html5.

it would also only have to do with javascript in case you use javascript serversided (like nodejs)

so basicly.. this has nothing to do with the tags you have choosen since final validation should never be done on the client side.

this problem is related to the server you are using but unless you tell us what server you are running and what language you are using on it and unless you show us some of your serversided upload code we might not be able to help you at all.